# Can't decrypt cookie with a custom domain name

Tags: cookies, azure, forms-authentication

I'm using an Windows Azure Cloud Service and when I access to it using my domain name instead of [CLOUDSERVICENAME].cloudapp.net I have problems with authentication cookies.

I'm creating the cookies

```
 FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                     1,
                     serializeModel.Username,
                     DateTime.Now,
                     DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15),
                     false,
                     userData);

        string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
        System.Web.HttpCookie faCookie = new System.Web.HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
        Response.Cookies.Add(faCookie);
```

But when I try to decrypt it I get a null value.

```
 HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

            if (authCookie != null)
            {
                FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

                JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(authTicket.UserData))
                {
```

This is strange since this only happens using my domain name to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that when I use my custom domain (running under a SSL Certificate) the cookie size increase. I believe that this is related with certificate encryption.

To solve this I have to remove some parameters from cookie userdata to guarantee that it doesn't grow to more than 4096 bytes (Browser Cookie Limits: http://browsercookielimits.x64.me/)